# Replace multiple occurrences of a comma with one comma

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, replace, cmd

The HR software we use allows for CSV files to be imported, however the dump we get from a third party isn't formatted as a CSV.

I have written a batch file to process it into a CSV file however there is one part of the dump file where there could be multiple spaces (it can be different for each line) and so when I replace spaces with commas I end up with multiple commas.

How can I update my batch file to change any occurrence of two or more commas to one comma?

Original file:

```
096 Parisella, Onorato - Perm            030417 05:53
000                                      030417 06:44
127 Thomas, Vincent - Perm               030417 06:44
040 Ram, Gurdial - Perm                  030417 07:09
100 Smano, Petros - Perm                 030417 07:12
128 Machenbach, Werner - Perm            030417 07:13
147 Samanovic, Milan                     030417 07:14
047 Hopkins, Hugo - Perm                 030417 07:16
```

My current batch file:

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "search= - Perm"
set "replace="

set "textFile=FINGERTEC RAW DATA*.txt"
set "rootDir=."

for %%j in ("%rootDir%\%textFile%") do (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%~j" ^& break ^> "%%~j"') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
        >>"%%~j" echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)

set "search= "
set "replace=,"

set "textFile=FINGERTEC RAW DATA*.txt"
set "rootDir=."

for %%j in ("%rootDir%\%textFile%") do (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%~j" ^& break ^> "%%~j"') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
        >>"%%~j" echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
```

Current output:

```
096,Parisella,,Onorato,,,,,,,,,,,,030417,05:53
000,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,030417,06:44
127,Thomas,,Vincent,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,030417,06:44
040,Ram,,Gurdial,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,030417,07:09
100,Smano,,Petros,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,030417,07:12
128,Machenbach,,Werner,,,,,,,,,,,,030417,07:13
147,Samanovic,,Milan,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,030417,07:14
047,Hopkins,,Hugo,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,030417,07:16
```

Please note that I cannot use any third party tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not specified the output you want.

This is the way I would do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "search= - Perm"
set "replace="

set "textFile=test.txt"
set "rootDir=."

for %%j in ("%rootDir%\%textFile%") do (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%~j" ^& break ^> "%%~j"') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        set "output="
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for %%a in (!line:%search%^=%replace%!) do set "output=!output!,%%a"
        >>"%%~j" echo(!output:~1!
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Output:

```
096,Parisella,Onorato,030417,05:53
000,030417,06:44
127,Thomas,Vincent,030417,06:44
040,Ram,Gurdial,030417,07:09
100,Smano,Petros,030417,07:12
128,Machenbach,Werner,030417,07:13
147,Samanovic,Milan,030417,07:14
047,Hopkins,Hugo,030417,07:16
```

Comment: This is what I was after. The output is what I wanted.